# Remove Packling PRO Drop Off Woocommerce Checkout Notice

Tags: function, hook-woocommerce

I want to remove the notice added by Packlink in my woocommerce checkout:

wp-content/plugins/packlink-pro-shipping/Components/Checkout/class-checkout-handler.php

```
    public function display_drop_off_message() {
        if (empty($fields['shipping']['address_1']) || empty($fields['shipping']['address_2']) || empty($fields['shipping']['city']) || empty($fields['shipping']['postcode'])) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'You have to enter your address first in order to search for Drop-Off location.', 'packlink-pro-shipping' ), 'notice' );
        }
    }
```

I tried with but it doesn't work
`remove_action('wc_add_notice', 'display_drop_off_message', 10 );`

Answer (score 0):

I am not developper or expert but I found how to correct this message.
I have deleted the contol on "address 2" which is not mandatory field.
Now the control is :

```
    /**
 * Displays message about drop-off locations search.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function display_drop_off_message() {
    if (empty($fields['shipping']['address_1']) || empty($fields['shipping']['city']) || empty($fields['shipping']['postcode'])) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'You have to enter your address first in order to search for Drop-Off location.', 'packlink-pro-shipping' ), 'notice' );
    }
}
```